# Redirect is not working in my case

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I have this component where I change this.props.route to redirect through redux.
In this case, I'm redirecting from '/aaa' to '/bbb' and it's not redirecting the page.

I tested if this.props.route gets change by adding console.log in the code and props are being updated but Redirect doesn't seem to work.

Basically, Component {aaa} updates the this.state.route from redux. Redux propagates the state to prop. Hence, RedirectHandler Component gets rerendered but Redirect is not firing.

This doesn't work.

RedirectHandler Component

```
render() {
  console.log('rerender', this.props.route); 1.) '/aaa' 2.) '/bbb'
  return(
  { this.props.isAuthenticated && <Redirect to={this.props.route} /> }

    <Route exact path="/" component={aaa} />
    <Route exact path="/aaa" component={aaa} />
    <Route exact path="/bbb" component={bbb} />
  )
}
```

Tho this works,

```
render() {
   return(
      { this.props.isAuthenticated && this.props.route === '/bbb' 
&& <Redirect to={this.props.route} /> }
      { this.props.isAuthenticated && <Redirect to={this.props.route} /> }

    <Route exact path="/" component={aaa} />
    <Route exact path="/aaa" component={aaa} />
    <Route exact path="/bbb" component={bbb} />
   )
 }
```

Question is, why it isn't redirecting me to the route specified on if the props.route are getting updated?

```
<Redirect to={this.props.route} />
```

OR

Why does the first block doesn't work while the second block does? :/

Comment: Are you getting any errors? `<Redirect to='this.props.route' />` does not work because you are passing a string `this.props.route`.

Comment: No errors at all, it's actually <Redirect to ={this.props.route} /> (a prop) which becomes "<Redirect to="/bbb" />

Comment: So you want the user to be redirected to another page programatically? Can you share your routes file? I'm not sure what you are trying to acheive here.

Comment: I edited the question, let me know if it's clearer.

Comment: I think you'll have to redirect inside a component with `history.push`, could you share the complete component? afaik you can't put routes inside a render method of a component.

Comment: Just add class RedirectHandler extends React.Component and it's already the whole RedirectHandlerComponent. I think you can put routes inside a render component (Source: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/examples/basic). To make it easier for the both of us :), kindly check the first and second block, the first block doesn't work, while the second one does which is the mystery to me.